# connect to a server with android 5.1.1

Tags: java, android, connection

I have a problem to connect with a server in some version of android.
I write the follow code in my class:

```
URL url = new URL("http://1-dot-f4nt4c4lc10c0mmun1ty.appspot.com/login");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

String inputString = user + "&" + pass;

connection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write(inputString);
out.close();
```

It works in the version 2.3.6 but in the version 5.1.1 and generally more of 4.0 it gives me this error

```
06-27 10:18:44.422: W/System.err(20562): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-27 10:18:44.422: W/System.err(20562):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at com.app.fantacalcio.Login.login(Login.java:63)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at com.app.fantacalcio.Login$2.onClick(Login.java:43)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
06-27 10:18:44.423: W/System.err(20562):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
06-27 10:24:03.901: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(20562): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are trying to hit web service on Main thread.
Android doesn't allow to hit web service on main thread from 2.3 onwards.

So hit Web service on backGround thread.

For this you can use AsynTask or thread.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to perform network related task. I recommend you to use [AsyncHttpClient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.html).